# $(z-k)$ is composite then $(z-1)+(k-1)$ is also composite(A proof for composite number).

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, solution-verification

> Given
>
> 1. $z(z-1)$  is divisible by all prime $< n$ where  $ n>\sqrt z$
> 2. $(z+k)$ is prime.
>
> Prove or disprove if $(z-k)$ is composite then $(z-1)+(k-1)$ is also composite.

**Proof**

$z-k=(z-1)-(k-1)=E$, where $E$ is a composite number, consider  $e$, where  $e | E$.
If $\gcd((z-1),(k-1))=g>1$ then  $(z-1)+(k-1)$ is composite.

If $\gcd((z-1),(k-1))=1$ then there is no such $e \mid E$, so that    $e \mid E$ and  $e \mid (z-1),(k-1)$ at the same time.
$e \not\mid z, k$ since  $(z+k)$ is prime,  which implies $(z,k)=1$.
So, $e \not\mid z, k, (z-1),(k-1)$.
But $E$ must have a prime $< E^{1/2} =(z-k)^{1/2}  <z^{1/2}<n .$ So, $((z-1),(k-1))>1 $since $((z-1),(k-1))=1$ does not allow  $E$ to have any prime of $z,(z-1)$. So, if $(z-k)$ is composite then $(z-1)+(k-1)$ is also composite.

> ** this mundane problem might have a relation to brocard's problem!! any kind of comment would help.

Comment: In a [tag:solution-verification] question your solution should be part of the question, not a separated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The proof you give is a bit unstructured and difficult to follow, and as a result not very convincing. However, the underlying idea seems to be correct. Here is almost the same proof, but rendered differently.

Assume $z$ and $k$ with $k < z$ are positive integers such that $z + k$ is prime, $z - k$ is composite, and any prime number smaller or equal to $\sqrt z$ divides $z(z-1)$. We want to prove that $(z - 1) + (k - 1)$ is composite.

Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $z - k$. Since $z - k$ is composite, it follows that $p \leq \sqrt{z - k} < \sqrt z$. By the assumption on $z$, it follows that $p$ divides $z(z -1)$. Since $p$ divides $z-k$ and does not divide $z+k$, $p$ does not divide $z$, and so we conclude that $p$ divides $z - 1$.

But then $p$ divides both $z-k$ and $z - 1$, so it also divides $k- 1$, and therefore also $(z -1) + (k - 1)$. In particular this last number is composite, and this is what we wanted to prove.

As a final remark, I would like to add that the assumption that any prime smaller than $\sqrt z$ divides $z(z - 1)$ forces $z$ to be smaller than $17^2 = 289$, since otherwise the product of all primes smaller than $\sqrt z$ is already (much) larger than $z(z-1)$. So one could also check all pairs $(z, k)$ satisfying your conditions with a computer.